# Agrupar registros relacionados con mayor valor en MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Buen dia amigos, tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
  i.cod_modular, a.idarchivo, m.descripcion, m.cantidad as cantidades,
  d.matriculados, (m.cantidad - d.matriculados) as deficit
FROM archivo a 
JOIN iiee i on i.cod_modular = a.iiee_cod_modular 
JOIN mobiliario m on m.archivo_idarchivo = a.idarchivo 
JOIN detalle d ON d.archivo_idarchivo = a.idarchivo 
WHERE m.descripcion like "%silla%" ORDER by a.idarchivo ASC
```

La cual me da el siguiente resultado:
[image: resultado de la consulta]

¿Cómo puedo sumar las cantidades de las sillas sólo de los `idarchivo` con mayor valor del `cod_modular`?

Espero su ayuda, saludos :)

Comment: que tengan el mismo idarchivo?

Comment: Si, agrupar por idarchivo, pero sumando al mismo tiempo las cantidades que coincidan con esa id

Comment: idarchivo es unico para cod_modular? o se puede repetir en otros cod_modular?

Comment: ¿Qué tal si nos pasas un dataset de pruebas con el resultado que esperas y así dejamos de dar palos de ciego? Es decir, por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo e incorpora el código de tus intentos. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener la suma se utiliza la función **sum()** agrupando por cod_modular, idarchivo y se ordena de mayor a menor, de esta manera tendremos los idarchivo mayores arriba en la consulta.

Después se encierra la consulta en otra consulta donde volvemos a agrupar pero solo por cod_modular, de esta manera nos dará solo un registro por cod_modular y gracias a que los idarchivo mayores están primero son el valor que se mantiene al agruparse.

La descripción previa es la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
t.*  from (SELECT
i.cod_modular, a.idarchivo, m.descripcion, sum(m.cantidad) as cantidades,
d.matriculados, (m.cantidad - d.matriculados) as deficit
FROM archivo a 
JOIN iiee i on i.cod_modular = a.iiee_cod_modular 
JOIN mobiliario m on m.archivo_idarchivo = a.idarchivo 
JOIN detalle d ON d.archivo_idarchivo = a.idarchivo 
WHERE m.descripcion like "%silla%" 
GROUP BY i.cod_modular, a.idarchivo ORDER by a.idarchivo DESC) t group by t.cod_modular
```

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, pero quiero obtener solo un registro por cada cod_modular, osea el idarchivo con mayor valor

Answer (score 0):

Esto debería funcionar aplicando SUM y utilizando GROUP BY HAVING() pera filtrar el resultado a solo los cod_modular con mayor idarchivo

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT
  i.cod_modular, a.idarchivo, m.descripcion, SUM(m.cantidad) as cantidades,
  d.matriculados, SUM(m.cantidad - d.matriculados) as deficit
FROM archivo a 
JOIN iiee i on i.cod_modular = a.iiee_cod_modular 
JOIN mobiliario m on m.archivo_idarchivo = a.idarchivo 
JOIN detalle d ON d.archivo_idarchivo = a.idarchivo 
WHERE m.descripcion like "%silla%" GROUP BY i.cod_modular,a.idarchivo) as q 
GROUP BY q.cod_modular HAVING(q.idarchivo = MAX(q.idarchivo)) ORDER by q.idarchivo ASC
```

Comment: No porque el idarchivo = MAX(idarchivo) esta en el HAVING no el el WHERE, traerá todos los datos agrupados por cod_modular y filtrara solo los idarchivo mayores, Saludos

Comment: Si lo use muchas veces cuando debo utilizar filtros que si pongo en el where no me traen todos los resultados que quiero, el MAX al estar dentro del HAVING lo que quiere decir es que traiga los valores agrupados por cod_modular que tengan el valor máximo de idarchivo, pero el parámetro de agrupación sigue siendo en este caso cod_modular

Comment: Perfecto entonces! debe ser porque mysql no respeta los groupby como corresponde. :) esperemos que OP lo pruebe y te de el ok

Comment: Así es si fuese SQLServer tendría que ser un poco mas complejo para que funcione

Comment: "No porque el idarchivo = MAX(idarchivo) esta en el HAVING no el el WHERE, traerá todos los datos agrupados por cod_modular y filtrara solo los idarchivo mayores, Saludos "-----> Jack, gracias por su ayuda, ha expresado muy bien la solución, sin embargo cuando lo ejecuto ese código no me muestra cod_modular que tienen 2 o más idarchivo diferentes, pero los que tienen  relación con un solo idarchivo me muestra correctamente.

Comment: Hola @krcode, actualice la consulta, confío en que esta ves mostrará el resultado esperado, Saludos

Comment: hola @JACK sigo con el mismo problema, no se muestran los registros que tienen dos o mas archivos diferentes. Sòlo se filtra los registros que tiene un solo idarchivo. :(

Answer (score 0):

No he podido probar la query ya que no has compartido los `CREATE TABLE` ni datos de prueba.

Si lo que quieres es obtener la suma de las cantidades para cada `cod_modular` y el mayor `idarchivo` de cada `cod_modular`, lo que puedes hacer luego de agrupar por `cod_modular` e `idarchivo` (y sumar las cantidades) subquery `sqCantidades`, es utilizar Window functions para filtrar solo el mayor `idarchivo` por cada `cod_modular`:

```
WITH sqCantidades AS (SELECT
                            i.cod_modular, 
                            a.idarchivo, 
                            SUM(m.cantidad) AS suma_cantidades
                      FROM archivo a 
                      INNER JOIN iiee i on i.cod_modular = a.iiee_cod_modular 
                      INNER JOIN mobiliario m on m.archivo_idarchivo = a.idarchivo 
                      INNER JOIN detalle d ON d.archivo_idarchivo = a.idarchivo 
                      WHERE m.descripcion like "%silla%" 
                      GROUP BY i.cod_modular, a.idarchivo)
                    
SELECT DISTINCT cod_modular, 
                FIRST_VALUE(idarchivo) OVER (PARTITION BY cod_modular ORDER BY idarchivo DESC) AS idarchivo,
                FIRST_VALUE(suma_cantidades) OVER (PARTITION BY cod_modular ORDER BY idarchivo DESC) AS suma_cantidades
FROM sqCantidades
ORDER by idarchivo ASC;
```